# Can a GridView scroll vertically without a wrapping ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have an GridView that gets bound to a data source in my C#, which loads more data as the user scrolls horizontally:

From GridView.xaml:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="GridViewStories" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource GridViewVerticalTemplate}" IsSwipeEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridViewStories_ItemClick" IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge">
    <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection />
    </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding SquareImageURL}" Margin="10" Width="240" Height="160" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I want this to behave like a ListView when in snapped view, meaning that it should scroll vertically instead of horizontally. Aside from this issue, I've been able to change everything I need through VisualStateManager:

From GridView.xaml:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelHeader" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelHeaderSnapped" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelHeaderPortrait" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewStories" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ItemsPanel">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource GridViewHorizontalTemplate}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

From StandardStyles.xaml:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="GridViewHorizontalTemplate">
    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I don't want to wrap the GridView in a Scrollviewer, because doing so breaks the built-in incremental loading I'm using. I realize that I could just create a ListView and toggle its and the GridView's visibilities, but I'd rather not have to bind to an extra control and duplicate other related code. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ItemsPanel` of your `GridView` to a horizontally oriented `StackPanel`?

Comment: Unfortunately Intellisense is telling me "ItemsPanel is not supported in a Windows App project."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give the whole item name.  See my edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `GridView`:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: LogMeIn's being a complete pain in the butt so I can't really test, but I did that, and once I removed the ItemsPanel property from the GridView, Intellisense accepted it. I will try to accomplish something similar in the VisualStateManager instead because I will only want this for snapped view. Tomorrow I'll be physically back at my work computer to do that and test. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you have to do `GridView.ItemsPanel` and not just `ItemsPanel`.

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm already setting the ItemsPanel property in the default XAML and the VisualStateManager to a template. I've tried modifying the template code, but that hasn't worked either, because I need to set WrapGrid properties (including Orientation="Horizontal"), and the ItemsPanelTemplate can only take one direct child. (Yes, I've tried nesting WrapGrid inside of StackPanel and vice versa, but neither has worked--both just crash the program on snapped.) Thanks for the idea, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView Name="display"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Height="550" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  SelectionMode="Single" >
    <GridView.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform Rotation="0"/>
    </GridView.RenderTransform>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD3D9DE" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBFB"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                </StackPanel.Background>
                <Grid x:Name="grdResultTxtBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500" Height="250" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="55" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="55" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"  />
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Button  Content="{Binding Call}" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource PnxButtonStyle}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Margin="0,10,200,0" x:Name="btnXmit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" />

                        <TextBlock  x:Name="txtAddress" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Address}" Margin="150,0,400,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"   Width="200"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```